# Socket.io best practices

Tags: node.js, sockets, websocket, socket.io

I am making an application live chat SAAS, and I intend to use socket.io, but some doubts arose.

1) I realized that all applications in the same category do not use socket, there some reason for this?

2) Socket.io is ready for medium / large-scale applications? It is a good choice?

3) I'm thinking of creating a room for each time conversation. This is a good practice?

4) To the service conversation, I better use room, namespace or otherwise?

5) A server with 2GB ram supports many socket connections about?

Thank you so much.

Answer (score 1):

> 1) I realized that all applications in the same category do not use socket, there some reason for this?

socket.io uses websockets (obviously) and falls back to HTTP. HTTP has well defined request and response definitions. Everyone knows what a 404 is right? socket.io is pretty new and how emits should behave is not well defined.

> 2) Socket.io is ready for medium / large-scale applications? It is a good choice?

Websockets are not as well supported as HTTP. NGINX provides good websocket support as a webserver and I can vouch for NGINX in this respect. Not all products provide such good support. e.g. if you want to use Google APIs do they support websockets? Unlikely!

> 3) I'm thinking of creating a room for each time conversation. This is a good practice?

That's not a development question. Research existing chat sites and make your own decisions :)

> 4) To the service conversation, I better use room, namespace or otherwise?

Sounds good.

> 5) A server with 2GB ram supports many socket connections about?

I don't know how well socket.IO scales.